# Excel slow reading

Tags: c#, excel

I want to read data from excel. I made this class:

```
public class Excel
{
    string path = "";
    _Application excel = new _Excel.Application();
    Workbook wb;
    Worksheet ws;
    public Excel(string path, int Sheet)
    {
        this.path = path;
        wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(path);
        ws = wb.Worksheets[Sheet];
    }

    public string ReadCell(int i, int j)
    {
        i++;
        j++;
        if (ws.Cells[i, j].Value2 != null)
        {
            try
            {
                double s = ws.Cells[i, j].Value2;
                string result = s.ToString();
                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return ws.Cells[i, j].Value2;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

This code works well, but it is very slow. I need to read about 1000 cells and it tooks mins...Is there any way how to do fast?

Comment: Often faster to `object iAmA2DArray = ws.GetRange("A1", "Z99");` then loop over the native array.

Comment: Another much faster alternative is to connect to the worksheet using ADO.NET.

Comment: Your whole `if-else` could be replace by  `return ws.Cells[i, j].Value2?.ToString() ?? "";`

Comment: Also, drop the Interop. Personally, I like EPPlus. Also this appears to be a duplicate: [Slow Performance When Reading Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32035946/slow-performance-when-reading-excel)